# Detect if someone is looking at firebug/chrome console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

I'd like to play a joke on a few friends. Because I don't want to hit the server several extra times every page i'd like the code to short circuit so it will only execute if the person has firebug or chrome console out.

Is there a way to detect if they are using the console?

If you're curious its because [the joke cant be seen unless in the console](https://github.com/escusado/console.meme/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: I don't think the server will be hit when they have the console closed, since the console then has no reason to load that image.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is :

```
 if (typeof window.console != 'undefined') {
     // Console is available. Do something.
 }
```